# How to cancel Django cache in fastcgi

Tags: python, django, apache

I am testing a web application on both shared host and Apache localhost,  using Django and fastcgi. When I edited my code and refreshing the page, many times the new code does not take effect. I think this is a cache issue, but I don't know how from the application.

For example: adding new url pattern to `mysite/urls.py` it does not take effect till I restart the Apache server on the localhost or waiting some time on the shared host.

I did not find any entries in `mysite/settings.py` that may allow any solution for that issue. I use Django 1.7 and Python 3.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the nature of using it in that format/setup.  On development, running as 'manage.py runserver' it auto reloads on file changes.
production/proxy setups like you have, you need to reload/restart the service to have changes take effect.

Comment: That is good on my localhost. However, what can I do on the shared host where I could access it from the SSH, is there any way?

Comment: your hosting provide may provide a way... you'll need to update your question with the setup and settings.